# Using ggplot2, how to set the Tick Marks intervals on y-axis without distorting my Boxplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I am using ggplot2 to create a Box Plot chart. My R codes stand as follows:

```
ggplot(mydata4, aes(PropertyCode,Total.Extras.Per.GN, fill=Original.Meal.Plan.Code))+
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape=NA) +
  ylim(c(0,1000))
```

This gives me the following output:

[image: Boxplot 1]

However after adding the following line of code to my existing codes, I end up with Figure 2 (shown below):

```
+ scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 1000, by=100))
```

[image: Boxplot 2]

As you can see, it distorts the whole graph. How do I go about maintaining my chart as Figure 1 and yet have the proper intervals displayed on the y-axis?

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I needed. If you post as an answer, I;ll give it my vote.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A solution is to substitute `ylim(c(0,1000))+scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 1000, by=100))` with `scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 1000, by=100), limits=c(0,1000))`:

```
ggplot(mydata4, aes(PropertyCode,Total.Extras.Per.GN, fill=Original.Meal.Plan.Code)) + 
geom_boxplot(outlier.shape=NA) + 
scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 1000, by=100), limits=c(0,1000))
```